# Не переведена отметка "Accepted" в списке ответов в профиле пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Пример:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor?tab=answers

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/2244

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2022.4.6.41881